# To find a word of a .txt, in parallel,

Tags: python

I have an RDD with some pairs of nun_adj,I would like to use mapPartitions to find the first `(adj, noun)` pair in which the noun is 'unification'

```
numPartitions = 10
lines = sc.textFile('adj_noun_pairs.txt', numPartitions)
pairs = lines.map(lambda l: tuple(l.split())).filter(lambda p: len(p)==2)
pairs.cache()

def f(iterator):
    for i in iterator:
    if (lambda x: 'unification' in x):
         yield i
    i+=1


result = lines.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

> File "", line 9, in f TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need
>   string or buffer, int found

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code:

```
numPartitions = 10
lines = sc.textFile('adj_noun_pairs.txt', numPartitions)
pairs = lines.map(lambda l: 
tuple(l.split())).filter(lambda p: len(p)==2)
pairs.cache()

def f(iterator):
    for i in iterator:
        if u'unification' == tuple(i)[1]:
            yield i


pairs.mapPartitions(f).first()
```

I use the `pairs` RDD you define but do not use.
Also I use `u'unification'` instead of `unification` since each word is of type `unicode` (I tested on Python 2 here, I don't think you need it in Python 3).
`i` is a collection of pairs, hence I iterate over it and yield the pair if "unification" is encountered.
`pairs.mapPartitions(f)` then is a collection of tuples (the first tuple for each partition), so I take the first.